# C# functions what is their true power and are they the same as methods

Tags: c#, .net, function

I often hear developers say C# functions are very powerful. Having heard this so often I believe it is true but having not used functions too often I still don't understand where their power lies. I have two  questions:

1) What is the true power of C# functions, where can they be applied?

2) Aren't normal methods the same as functions, for example what is the difference with the two below:

```
public int GetNumberOfDays(int randomVariable);
```

and

```
Func<int,int>
```

Comment: Could they be talking about the "functional programming" part of C#?

Comment: Sounds more likely.  Although there are still languages that are much better at it than C#.  FP is still kinda new to C# yet.

Comment: @M.Babcock Actually, `function<int, int>();` looks like call to a generic method named "function" having two type parameters.  The type `Func<int, int>` is a delegate type; lambda expressions may be converted to delegate types, but delegate types don't represent lambda expressions; they can also represent normal methods.

Comment: @phoog - You're right. I must have been disoriented by how unconstructive the question really is.

Comment: General_9: you'll need to clarify exactly what you mean by function.  It could refer to the `Func` family of delegate types; it could be a synonym for "method" (or for "non-void method", as in Visual Basic); and it could, as others have noted, refer to lambda expressions (although that would be rather ambiguous, since lambda expressions can be compiled to delegates or to expression trees).

Comment: @M.Babcock I agree the question is somewhat disorienting.  It took me a while to work out how `function<int, int>();` could be legal code.  General_9: `public int GetNumberOfDays(int randomVariable);` is illegal.  There are a few possible changes to make it legal, but it's not possible to know which change to suggest, since we don't know what it is intended to represent.

Comment: Yes sorry I mean't Func<int,int> not function<int, int>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Func<int, int>` is a delegate type that represents a method that takes one parameter of type `int` and returns an `int`.  Delegates are powerful: they allow you to pass one or more functions to another function.  Delegates have other powers as well, but I will ignore them for this discussion.

Passing a function to another function is a key concept with Linq to Objects:

```
int TimesTwo(int arg) { return arg * 2; }

int TimesThree(int arg) { return arg * 3; }

IEnumerable<int> DoubleTheSequence(IEnumerable<int> input)
{
    return input.Select(TimesTwo);
}

IEnumerable<int> TripleTheSequence(IEnumerable<int> input)
{
    return input.Select(TimesThree);
}
```

In this case, we are using the `Select` method, which takes a sequence and a function and returns the sequence that results from applying the function to each member of the input sequence.

In the example above, `TimesTwo` and `TimesThree` are passed to the Select method by virtue of "implicit method group conversion".  In short, the compiler converts the bare method name to a delegate that refers to the correct overload of the method.  The term is "method *group*" because when a method is overloaded, the name refers to all of the overloads as a group, and the compiler must choose the correct overload.

It can be inconvenient to write several methods simply because we want to pass them to other methods.  That's why C# introduced *anonymous delegates* and, later, the more concise *lambda expression*.  Now, suppose we want to be able to quadruple our sequence in addition to doubling or tripling it.  Instead of writing a new function called `TimesFour`, we can use a lambda:

```
IEnumerable<int> QuadrupleTheSequence(IEnumerable<int> input)
{
    return input.Select(i => i * 4);
}
```

Finally, we could make a more generic `TransformTheSequenceInSomeArbitraryManner` method:

```
IEnumerable<int> TransformTheSequenceInSomeArbitraryManner(IEnumerable<int> input, Func<int, int> f)
{
    return input.Select(f);
}
```

That example is obviously just a trivial wrapper around the `Select` method, but it serves to illustrate how you would declare a method that takes a `Func<int, int>` parameter.  This method shows two ways of *using* that parameter:

```
int CallTheFunctionTwice(int input, Func<int, int> f)
{
    int intermediateValue = f.Invoke(input);
    int result = f(intermediateValue);
    return result;
}
```

Specifically, you can invoke a delegate either by calling its `Invoke` method explicitly, or with method-call syntax.  The compiled code is identical for either approach.

Finally, to answer your question:

> What is the difference between `public int GetNumberOfDays(int randomVariable)` and `Func<int,int>`?

The first is a method declaration; it declares a specific method that takes an `int` argument and returns a specific `int` whose value presumably depends on the value of the argument.  The second is a delegate type that can hold a reference to *any* method with the same signature.

Answer (score 3):

```
function<int, int>(); is not right
```

you meant :

```
Func<int,int>
```

its just a sugar syntax for

```
int delegate func(int a)
```

forexample :

```
public void PrintMe(Func<int,int> f,string s)
{
}
```